# Stubbing methods in Java

Tags: java, junit

I am coming from a ruby/rails background and am trying to test with JUnit a Java project that I am working on.

I am looking for a library similar to Mocha with Rspec but for Java.

What exactly I am trying to do is something similar to this:

Model.any_instance.stubs(:method).returns('foo').

The goal being to stub the answer of any call to a method for the given instance of a class.

Any idea? I looked at Mockito, but could not find a way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

With Mockito you can do

```
MyClass myObj = mock(MyClass.class);
when(myObj.callMyMethod(any(Integer.class)).thenReturn("foo");
```

providing callMyMethod takes an Integer, and returns a String.

You can specify exact arguments instead of any(???.class) if you'd rather be more specific.

Comment: I forgot - mock and when are static methods on the org.mockito.Mockito class.

Comment: and any() is a static method on org.mockito.Matchers

Answer (score 2):

You can look EasyMock Framework, it's very easy to use and have a good community. You can find documentation here [EasyMock documentation](http://easymock.org/Documentation.html)

Answer (score 0):

try [anystub](https://anystub-guides.github.io/). it's for switchers from rails.